# Have an electronic and physical stalker with access to my computer when I am online

Tags: account-security

I have an ongoing electronic and physical stalking situation. Someone has hacked my computer and is able to at times see my activities such as sending email and shopping. They also took screenshots off the screen of my computer while I had the Dashboard to my security system open. I have a lot of ssh.exe and related files over and over, many of them recurring on the same day. I do not know if this could be related to the hacking. I have Remote Desktop disabled. I have blocked every kind of sharing I can figure out in the firewall. I have deleted connected devices repeatedly from the services (although they reappear after I turn my computer off and then on again).

My internet provider said it could be hacked via my router. (This is Sprint. It is their router but they have done nothing to remedy the situation) I have a separate internet account that I pay for but I live in an apartment building with Sprint WiFi that is provided with each apartment.

Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: The question is very broad and does not provide enough details to help you. I think your best approach is to bring the computer to a shop and have somebody look at it locally.

Comment: Wipe clean, i.e. format everything and reinstall from known to be clean media.

Comment: @fleitner if the system is compromised, there's no point in "looking". It's done. It's impossible to know the extent and how it's been compromised, thus using it is unsafe, period.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I agree, a compromised system is insecure and must be rebuilt. Based on the vagueness of the description I suggested going to a PC shop as I have doubts OP has the background to rebuild it properly (as opposed to just reinstalling the OS over the existing one).